# How can I get the value of a custom attribute using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can I get the value of a custom attribute using jQuery?

```
<a href="" custom="this value">
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr/ -- that's the first hit I get for googling `jquery get attribute`.

Comment: (this).attr('customTag')

Comment: api.jquery.com/attr - nothing on custom tags in a link

Comment: Does not change the fact that it works. If you can't get it to work, you might have an error in your code. In that case you should post your code, otherwise, how do you expect us to be able to help you?

Comment: like @elliot said, prepend your attributes with "data" to be valid, but it really will work anyway.  http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: Sounds like a case of "I've tried nothing and it's not working". As everyone is saying, you really should use something like `data-custom` which is a valid attribute. Google up "HTML5 data attributes".

Answer (score 2):

```
var value = $('#ELEMENT-ID').attr('the-attribute');
```

Where `ELEMENT-ID` is a place holder for your element `id`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rXXVZ/)

Note that custom attributes are not valid HTML, though in almost every modern browsers they will be ignored.

Any way, you should give your custom attributes a prefix of `data-` like:
`data-the-attribute`

You can use jQuery `data` to get this value:

```
var value = $('#ELEMENT-ID').data('the-attribute');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3wZnn/)

Comment: Doesn't work when you try and use custom attributes in a link

Comment: @user1116475. It does work! I'll give you a fiddle in a minute

Comment: @gdoron that sounds so dirty :D

Answer (score 1):

While it is indeed possible to set and retrieve custom attributes, it would be better as a rule to use the [`data-*`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) system.

**Example HTML:**

```
<p id="someElement" data-myValue="myValue"> Hello world </p>
```

**Example Javascript:**

```
// to get a data-* attribute:
var someVariable = $("#someElement").data("myValue");

// to set a data-* attribute:
$("#someElement").data("myValue", someVariable);
```

Comment: I'd upvote if you elaborated on that.

Comment: @Blazemonger: Fair enough, updating.

Comment: Btw, don't make the same mistake as the OP. There is no such thing as an "attribute tag".

Comment: isn't this only valid if the OP is actually using HTML5 doctype?

Comment: @peroija: No, HTML5 is inferred I believe. Unless of course you specify otherwise.

Comment: Can I ask why this was downvoted...?

Answer (score 1):

use the following, for example your custom attribute name is "`custom"`

```
var mycustomattributevalue = $("a").attr("custom");
```